# If Statement Isn't Working with Two <Long> Lists [Java]

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

```
long temp;
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
    temp = ls.get(i);
    System.out.println("temp is:" + temp);
    for ( int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
            if ( i == j )
            {

            }
            else if ( ls.get(i) == ls.get(j) )
            {
                // If Duplicate, do stuff... Dunno what yet.
                System.out.println(ls.get(i)+" is the same as: " + ls.get(j) );
                //System.out.println("Duplicate");
            }

    }
}
```

I have a List of type Long, it is filled with several 9 digit numbers like 900876012, I am checking for duplicates so that I can generate new numbers and replace the duplicate before exporting to a file.

First, I check to see if the position in the array is the same, since obviously something at position 1 is going to be the same in the same list at position 1, if so, ignore.

Then, I check to see if the contents are the same, but it doesn't evaluate as true for some reason, it did before as a plain "if" on its own.

For reference here's the numbers, just ignore the "temp is":

```
temp is:900876512
temp is:765867999
temp is:465979798
temp is:760098908
temp is:529086890
temp is:765867999
temp is:529086890
temp is:800003243
temp is:200900210
temp is:200900210
temp is:542087665
temp is:900876512
temp is:900876512
temp is:900876512
temp is:900876512
```

Here's the full method for reference:

```
public static void CheckContents(BufferedReader inFileStreamName, File aFile, Scanner s ) throws DuplicateSerialNumberException
{
    System.out.println();
    List<Long> ls = new ArrayList<Long>();
    List<String> ls2 = new ArrayList<String>();

long SerialNum = 0;
int counter = 0;
int size = 0;
String StringBuffer;

while (s.hasNextLine())
{
    ls.add(s.nextLong());
    //System.out.println();
    StringBuffer = s.nextLine();
    ls2.add(StringBuffer);
    size = ls.size();
    //System.out.println(ls.size());
    SerialNum = ls.get(size-1);
    //System.out.println(ls.get(size-1));
    System.out.println("Serial # is: " + SerialNum);
    //System.out.println(SerialNum + ": " + StringBuffer);
    counter++;
}

long temp;
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
    temp = ls.get(i);
    System.out.println("temp is:" + temp);
    for ( int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if ( i == j )
        {

        }
        else if ( ls.get(i) == ls.get(j) )
        {
            // If Duplicate, do stuff... Dunno what yet.
            System.out.println(ls.get(i)+" is the same as: " + ls.get(j) );
            //System.out.println("Duplicate");
        }

    }
}


}
```

Comment: For some reason when I make ls.get(j) = temp and then evaluate ls.get(i) with temp, this works properly, but not ls.get(i) with ls.get(j)... Code now works for now but would be nice to know why that is...

Comment: It is called autoboxing. In the list you can only store objects, but when you assign it to a primitive the conversión is automatic (and when you add the primitive to the list, the conversión to object is automatic too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice one.

In the list you don't store `float` (primitive) but `Float` objects. Autoboxing makes you transparent to you.

And the `==` comparator does not work with objects (it tells if both objects are the same, but if you have two object holding the same value it returns `false`).

You can use

```
   if ( ls.get(j).equals(ls.get(i))
```

or (since it is `List<Long>`)

```
   if ( ls.get(j).longValue() == ls.get(i).longValue())
```

or even (thanks to autoboxing)

```
   if ( ls.get(j).longValue() == ls.get(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
else if ( ls.get(i) != null && ls.get(i).equals(ls.get(j)) )
```

instead

Comment: Wow, I should've realized it was stored as an object and not a primitive, not sure which one to mark as correct as both are helpful :D

Comment: SJuan's answer is more complete, so you've done good accepting his one